# Making nextcloud work on a prefixed path (using docker and caddy)

Tags: docker-compose, caddyfile

I'm trying to setup my own instance of nextcloud on my server but I'm running into a problem as I want nextcloud to be available under https://example.com/cloud/.

Next cloud is running in a CoreOS virtual machine called let's say myvm.
So this is the way I setup my CaddyFile:

```
example.com {
    gzip

    proxy /cloud myvm:8080 {
        transparent
        without /cloud
    }
}
```

I have other proxies that work fine for other services or VMs that are written similarily.

With this, and publishing port 8080 in my docker-compose file, I manage to connect to the nextcloud instance. But every time I go to `example.com/cloud/` it will redirect me to `example.com/apps/files/` instead of `example.com/cloud/apps/files/`.
If I enter this last url manually, I can access to nextcloud, but also the page doesn't load properly because all the contents cannot be loaded because they are not prompted with the prefix `cloud/`.

Is there a way to explain nextcloud about this prefix through the configuration of docker-compose file? (It's the only configuration I created, it works with just that and no extra work, I use one similar to the one available [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/nextcloud/) (the apache one).)
Or maybe I can improve the CaddyFile config? (By the way, if I don't use the `without` option, it will just not work at all and return 404 when I go to the url).